# Unable to create user on windows server 2008 due to access permission

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, user-accounts, windows-users

I am getting below error while trying to create user on remote computer.

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: General access denied error at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo() at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoMachineInit() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ContextForType(Type t) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetStoreCtxToUse() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.set_DisplayName(String value) at testemail.CreateLocalWindowsAccount(String username, String password, String displayName, String description, Boolean canChangePwd, Boolean pwdExpires)

here is the code.

```
public void CreateLocalWindowsAccount(string username, string password, string displayName, string description, bool canChangePwd, bool pwdExpires)
    {
        try
        {
            PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "127.0.0.1");
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
            user.SetPassword(password);
            user.DisplayName = displayName;
            user.Name = username;
            user.Description = description;
            user.UserCannotChangePassword = canChangePwd;
            user.PasswordNeverExpires = pwdExpires;
            user.Save();

            //now add user to "Users" group so it displays in Control Panel
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Remote Desktop Users");
            group.Members.Add(user);
            group.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this application under an account that has sufficient privileges to create accounts on the remote server? If not then you will have to grant sufficient permissions to the account that you are running your application under.

Comment: I am running this code in a website. That website is hosted on windows server 2008.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question: have you configured your website to run under an account that has sufficient privileges? Apparently you haven't thus the exception you are getting.

Comment: yes, website is running under administrator account.

Comment: But is this a local administrator account? It looks like you are trying to create accounts on some other machine. Does this account has sufficient privileges on this remote machine?

Comment: Yes, its local administrator account and i am trying to create a user account on the same machine thats why i wrote 127.0.0.1( means local machine). Is it incorrect?

Comment: After changing the local IP(127.0.0.1) to that particular IP of the machine, the code gets executed without any exception or error but its not creating the user under specified user group.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Have you checked my code after above comment?